# Check whether a cell contains a substring

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there an in-built function to check if a cell contains a given character/substring?

It would mean you can apply textual functions like `Left`/`Right`/`Mid` on a conditional basis without throwing errors when delimiting characters are absent.

Answer (score 420, accepted):

Try using this:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Some Text", A3))
```

This will return `TRUE` if cell `A3` contains `Some Text`.

Comment: Cunning! Thanks gwin003 :) I'm still a bit surprised there's not a more intuitive function for this.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it would be nice if there were a `CONTAINS("Text", cell)` function.

Comment: Something I got stuck on at first: you really need to use `ISNUMBER` as well as `SEARCH`. I was using this inside an `IF` and came up with: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$1,A73)), A73, B73)`

Comment: I guess the above also does the same, only addition is that if true out A73 value in the cell, if false, B73 value

Comment: might be worth it to note that this i case insensitive, and if you want to match case, you should use `FIND()` in place of `SEARCH()`

Comment: got an error using `,` instead of `;`. After changing the provided formula to `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Some Text"; A3))` it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @renatov that actually depends on the _locale_ of your OS; specifically, the character used for "list separator".

Comment: It's way too long of code! IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(...),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(...)))
THAT'S CRAZY TO READ!!! It should be:
If( C4.Contains("something") OR C4.Contains("somethingelse"))
so it can be readable and maintainable.

Comment: Excel has been around for so long and it still doesn't have a good expression builder. I recently started doing Telerik reports and I'm actually decently happy with building expressions using the expression builder. Can compare things by choosing from a drop down menu of options such as "=", "<>", "Contains", "Starts With". So much easier. If it's gotta be code then lets use normal code like JS. Otherwise use an expression builder that is easy to use.

Comment: If you want to use the result (string position) in a subsequent operation (MID), suggest IFERROR, e.g. `IFERROR(SEARCH("Some Text", A3), 0)`.

Comment: Just to be sure you not actually matching a substring within another substring (yes that's a thing) you could use `=ISNUMBER(FIND(" Some Text ", " "&A3" "))` Notice the spaces.

Answer (score 27):

The following formula determines if the text "CHECK" appears in cell C10.  If it does not, the result is blank.  If it does, the result is the work "CHECK".

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("CHECK",C10,1)),"","CHECK")
```

Comment: You can use 4 spaces or tab at beginning of the line to highlight the code block.

Answer (score 18):

For those who would like to do this using a single function inside the IF statement, I use

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*TEXT*"),TrueValue,FalseValue)
```

to see if the substring TEXT is in cell A1

[NOTE: TEXT needs to have asterisks around it]

Comment: It works, but use of COUNTIF formula when huge data, makes file not responding, even file size becomes huge

Answer (score 14):

This formula seems more intuitive to me:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"SomeText","") <> A1
```

this returns TRUE if "SomeText" is contained within A1.

The IsNumber/Search and IsError/Find formulas mentioned in the other answers certainly do work, but I always find myself needing to look at the help or experimenting in Excel too often with those ones.

Answer (score 9):

Check out the `FIND()` function in Excel.

Syntax:

```
FIND( substring, string, [start_position])
```

Returns `#VALUE!` if it doesn't find the substring.

Comment: Yes nested in `ISNUMBER` this also works, for case-sensitive matches only.

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question but I think it is still valid.

Since there is no CONTAINS function, why not declare it in VBA?
The code below uses the VBA Instr function, which looks for a substring in a string. It returns 0 when the string is not found.

```
Public Function CONTAINS(TextString As String, SubString As String) As Integer
    CONTAINS = InStr(1, TextString, SubString)
End Function
```

Comment: Good way to improve personal efficiency, but at the cost of reproducibility I'd say :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply

```
COUNTIF(A1,"*xyz*")
```

This searches for any appearence of "xyz" in cell A1.

It returns "1" when found, and "0" when not found.

Attention, the search is not case sensitive, so any of xyz, XYZ, XyZ, and so on will be found. It finds this as substrings in the cell, so also for abcxYz you get a hit.

If you do not want to write your search string into the formula itself, you can use

```
COUNTIF(A1,"*" & B1 & "*")
```

and enter your search string into B1. - Attention, when B1 is empty, the formula will return "found" ("1") as the search string is then read as "**".

Answer (score 2):

I like Rink.Attendant.6 answer.  I actually want to check for multiple strings and did it this way:

First the situation: Names that can be home builders or community names and I need to bucket the builders as one group.  To do this I am looking for the word "builder" or "construction", etc.  So -

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(A1,"*builder*"),COUNTIF(A1,"*builder*")),"Builder","Community")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should read up on what makes a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't understand what this is meant to do.. it checks for builder twice when presumably once would suffice. If it finds builder it returns builder, else it returns community. The word construction doesn't appear anywhere. Perhaps something like `=OR(COUNTIF(A1,"*builder*"),COUNTIF(A1,"*construction*"))`?

Comment: There is `COUNTIFS`: `COUNTIFS(A1,"*builder*",A1,"*construction*")`

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but a solution for those using Excel 2016 or newer is you can remove the need for nested if structures by using the new `IFS( condition1, return1 [,condition2, return2] ...)` conditional.

I have formatted it to make it visually clearer on how to use it for the case of this question:

```
=IFS(
ISERROR(SEARCH("String1",A1))=FALSE,"Something1",
ISERROR(SEARCH("String2",A1))=FALSE,"Something2",
ISERROR(SEARCH("String3",A1))=FALSE,"Something3"
)
```

Since `SEARCH` returns an error if a string is not found I wrapped it with an `ISERROR(...)=FALSE` to check for truth and then return the value wanted. It would be great if `SEARCH` returned 0 instead of an error for readability, but thats just how it works unfortunately.

Another note of importance is that `IFS` will return the match that it finds first and thus ordering is important. For example if my strings were `Surf, Surfing, Surfs` as `String1,String2,String3` above and my cells string was `Surfing` it would match on the first term instead of the second because of the substring being `Surf`. Thus common denominators need to be last in the list. My `IFS` would need to be ordered `Surfing, Surfs, Surf` to work correctly (swapping `Surfing` and `Surfs` would also work in this simple example), but `Surf` would need to be last.

Comment: most will want if/else ability, in other words a default value.  Adding this quote might broaden the appeal of your answer:   "There is no way to set a default if all tests return FALSE (i.e. a value if false). Instead, enter TRUE for the last test, and then a value to return as a default value if FALSE"

Comment: IFS was added in Excel 2019, it is not present in Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

*Interesting* *

```
=COUNT(MATCH("*SomeText*",A1,))
=COUNTA(VLOOKUP("*SomeText*",A1,1,))
=COUNTA(HLOOKUP("*SomeText*",A1,1,))
```

*this returns 1 if "SomeText" is contained within A1.*

Comment: You could add `>0` on the end to return a boolean.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the formula I'm using

`=IF( ISNUMBER(FIND(".",A1)), LEN(A1) - FIND(".",A1), 0 )`

Comment: This checks to see if "." is included in A1, and if it is, it returns... the number of characters remaining in A1, starting with ".". Not sure whether that additional calculation is relevant here.

Comment: Leastwise, use `IFERROR(LEN(A1) - FIND(".", A1), 0)`