# find the first instance of a specif character and get the left value using vba

Tags: excel, vba

How to find the first instance of a specif character and get the left value using vba

a= "\abc\123\abc\test\test123\123\1248\1234\Dec 03"

I need the output as "\abc\123\abc\test\test123\123\1248\1234", that is it should detect the first \ and get remaining string from the left using VBA.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php

Comment: Detect first \ from where?

Comment: I need complete string before the first "\". In my example the original string is "\abc\123\abc\test\test123\123\1248\1234\Dec 03" I need the result like "\abc\123\abc\test\test123\123\1248\1234"

Comment: The first \ is \abs. Then *string before it* doesn't make a sense.

Comment: first "\" from the back side. in my example last "\" is present near '\Dec 03"

Comment: *from the back side* Yeah, this tiny detail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub str()
    Dim a As String
    a = "\abc\123\abc\test\test123\123\1248\1234\Dec 03"

    Dim ret As String
    ret = Left(a, InStrRev(a, "\") - 1)

    Debug.Print ret
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice - OP did say "find a specific character", so maybe add a parameter to the sub that lets the user define that character? But that's not mentioned anywhere by OP in posts or comments, just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mis-stating your goal.  It looks like you want to keep the entire string, *except* the last part as delimited by a `\`.

This formula should work (thanks to [@Tobin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25320506/4650297)):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))-1)
```

[image]

For VBA, you can use:

```
Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=LEFT(RC[-1],FIND(""@"",SUBSTITUTE(RC[-1],""\"",""@"",LEN(RC[-1])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-1],""\"",""""))))-1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the string you want to modify appears in Sheet1.Range("A1").
2. The result would appears at Sheet1.Range("A2").

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim NoCh As Integer
    Dim i As Long, LP As Long
    Dim str As String

        str = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
        NoCh = Len(str)


        For i = NoCh To 1 Step -1
            If Mid(str, i - 1, 1) = "\" Then
                LP = i
                Exit For
            End If

        Next i

        Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = Left(str, LP - 2)

End Sub
```