# How to make a VBA code in Excel to copy and paste only certain values in a cell

Tags: excel, copy, paste, vba

I have a project that deals with thousands of file names in Excel.

```
S:\Workgroups\APC Environmental Affairs\WATER\`New File Structure\PLANTS\HYDRO\HENRY\SPCC\correspondence\Henry SPCC NEW REVISION.msg
```

The complete file location is listed in the cells. I would need to copy over only the true file name "Henry SPCC NEW REVISION" into a new cell over

```
S:\Workgroups\APC Environmental Affairs\WATER\`New File Structure\PLANTS\HYDRO\HENRY\SPCC\correspondence\Henry SPCC Plans.msg
```

For this one I would copy over "Henry SPCC Plans".  **Basically I'm copying over the text between the last \ and the .file extension**.

**Is there a macro or special paste function I can use to help me with this?**

Answer (score 0):

As part of [tigeravatar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string) answer, you can use:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```