# How do I find the position of the last alphanumeric character in an Excel string using an Excel formula?

Tags: excel-formula

For example, in the string VA4940--05-LAMB  --,%2--, 2 is the last alphanumeric character.  It is in the 22nd spot.  I'm looking for a formula that will return "22".

Thanks to everyone who responded.  This gave me the answer I'm looking for, specifically tiger's.  All were helpful, though.

Comment: Is it out of question to write a dedicated VBA function and use it in the formula?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string

Comment: If at all possible, I'd like to avoid VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate regular formula (no array entry required) solution:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))
```

Also, given your provided sample string `VA4940--05-LAMB --,%2--` the last alphanumeric character (2) is at position 21, not 22.

Same formula, but without using INDIRECT (it's a volatile function and should generally be avoided).  This formula also assumes the maximum length of any given string is 99 or less.  Adjust the 99's to be higher if necessary:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(A1&REPT(" ",99),ROW($1:$99),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"))),ROW($1:$99))
```

Comment: This did it!  Thank you so much.  My upvotes don't count yet, but you got one.

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't** want a dedicated VBA function, here's one way. Start with:

```
=ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1))
{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23}
```

entered as an array formula (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER --- **all of the formulas in this answer will be array formulas**). As shown, this will generate a series of integers 1, 2, ... LEN(MyStr), where MyStr is your target string and F1 can be any cell in row 1.

Embed that in the `MID` function to produce an array of single chars in MyStr:

```
=MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1)
{"V";"A";"4";"9";"4";"0";"-";"-";"0";"5";"-";"L";"A";"M";"B";" ";"-";"-";",";"%";"2";"-";"-"}
```

The `UPPER` function is used as a convenience so that there's no need to test for lower case alpha-chars.

Embed that in the `CODE` function to produce an array of ASCII codes:

```
=CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))
{86;65;52;57;52;48;45;45;48;53;45;76;65;77;66;32;45;45;44;37;50;45;45}
```

Now determine which ones are (upper case) letters. An `IF` function test those codes against the condition `>=CODE("A")`. If that test passes, we'll perform another test against the condition `<=CODE("Z")`. If both tests pass, we know it's a letter, so return the character position. Otherwise return a zero.

```
=IF(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))>=CODE("A"),IF(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))<=CODE("Z"),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),0),0)
{1;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;12;13;14;15;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}
```

We've only tested for alpha chars so far. Now instead of returning 0 if the first test failed, substitute an analogous test for digits:

```
=IF(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))>=CODE("A"),IF(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))<=CODE("Z"),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),0),IF(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))>=CODE("0"),IF(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))<=CODE("9"),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),0),0))
{1;2;3;4;5;6;0;0;9;10;0;12;13;14;15;0;0;0;0;0;21;0;0}
```

Finally, to get the last matching char take the `MAX` of the entire thing:

```
=MAX(IF(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))>=CODE("A"),IF(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))<=CODE("Z"),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),0),IF(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))>=CODE("0"),IF(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),1))<=CODE("9"),ROW(OFFSET(F1,0,0,LEN(MyStr),1)),0),0)))
```

which returns 21 (not 22 --- 22 is wrong).

A VBA custom function is surely more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

To find the `position` of the **First** or **Last** **Character\Type** in a string use the following `Array Formula`:

```
= [First or Last] (
CHOOSE( LOOKUP( CODE( UPPER(
MID( Cll , ROW( $A$1 : INDEX( $A:$A , LEN( Cll ) , 0 )), 1))),
[Lookup Array] ), "" ,
ROW( $A$1 : INDEX( $A:$A , LEN( Cll )))))
```

Where:

[**First** or **Last**]: Use `MIN` for **First** Character or `MAX` for **Last** Character

**Cll**: Cell containing the string to search

[**Lookup Array**]: Array to use for validation based on *Type of Character* to find

**Type of Character - Classification** *(see Fig. 1)*

**Numeric**: 0 to 9

**Alpha**: A to Z  *(lower & upper case)*

**Alpha International**: Š Ž Ÿ À Á Â Ã Ä Å Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö Ù Ú Û Ü Ý  *(lower & upper case)*

**Other Characters**: Any other ASCII character

[image]*Fig. 1*

**Lookup Array to use for each Type of Character** * -  Short Array to be used with `UPPER` function *(see Fig. 2)*

**Numeric**: `{1,1;48,2;58,1}`

**Alpha**: `{1,1;65,2;91,1}`

**Alpha International**: `{1,1;138,2;139,1;142,2;143,1;159,2;160,1;192,2;
                      198,1;199,2;208,1;209,2;215,1;217,2;222,1}`

**Other Characters:** `{1,2;48,1;58,2;65,1;91,2;97,1;123,2;131,1;132,2;138,1;
                    139,2;142,1;143,2;154,1;155,2;156,1;157,2;158,1;160,2;192,1;
                    198,2;199,1;208,2;209,1;215,2;217,1;222,2;224,1;247,2;248,1}`

[image]

*Fig. 2*

These arrays can be combined as needed, for example in this case the question asks to **find the Last Alphanumeric character in the string**, for that we'll use the Numeric and Alpha arrays combined.

**String**: `VA4940--05-LAMB --,%2--`

For this sample this string is located in cell `C21`

Let’s replace the arguments of the Array Formula:

[**First** or **Last**] => `MAX`

**Cll**     => `C21`

[**Lookup Array**]  => `'{1,1;48,2;58,1;65,2;91,1}` - *Alphanumeric*

Enter the following Array Formula in cell `G24`:

`=MAX(CHOOSE(LOOKUP(
CODE(UPPER(MID($C21,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($C21),0)),1))),
{1,1;48,2;58,1;65,2;91,1}),"",
ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($C21)))))`

Basically what the formulas does is:

1. Creates a vertical array assigning each character of the string into each row, the height of the array is automatically defined by the length of the string.

`MID($C21,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($C21),0)),1))`

*Partial result:* `{V, A, 4, 9, 4, 0, -, -, 0, 5, -, L, A, M, B,  , -, -, ,, %, 2, -, -}`

2. Validates the upper case ASCII Codes of the characters in each row of the vertical array against the Lookup Vector assigning 1 if failed or 2 if passed the validation.

`LOOKUP(CODE(UPPER(
{V, A, 4, 9, 4, 0, -, -, 0, 5, -, L, A, M, B,  , -, -, ,, %, 2, -, -}),
{1,1;48,2;58,1;65,2;91,1})`

*Partial result:* `{2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1}`

3. Fills up the array based on prior validation assigning the row number within the array (or position) to those who passed the validation and leaving blank the records that failed.

`CHOOSE({2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1},"",
ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($C21))))`

*Partial result:* `{1,2,3,4,5,6,,,9,10,,12,13,14,15,,,,,,21,,}`

4. Finally retrieves the `MAX` *(as we’re looking for the last character)* value in the array, representing the last valid row in the array complying with the Lookup Array condition.

`MAX({1,2,3,4,5,6,,,9,10,,12,13,14,15,,,,,,21,,})`

**Position** `21`

See Fig. 3 with additional samples.
[image]

*Fig. 3*

Comment: Wow.  That is impressive.  Thanks so much for your help.  I'll attempt this on Monday and let you know how it goes.