# Trim leading and trailing spaces but leave all spaces between words alone

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The TRIM function eliminates duplicated spaces inside the string as well as trimming off leading and trailing spaces. I need to trim off leading and trailing spaces, but leave duplicated spaces in the middle of the string alone.

Is there a way to do this in an Excel formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that's easily done with just formula.
This VBA will do the job:

```
Public Function TRIMLR(Target As Range) As Variant

    TRIMLR = RTrim(LTrim(Target.Value))

End Function
```

As pnuts says in his comment - this will do the job:

```
Public Function TRIMLR(Target As Range) As Variant

    TRIMLR = Trim(Target.Value)

End Function
```

Have now found a couple of formula at this website, just need to figure out how to combine the two formula:
 http://eforexcel.com/wp/article-18-ltrim-and-rtrim-through-excel-formulas/
LTRIM:
**=REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),A1)-1,"")**
RTRIM:
 **=IFERROR(REPLACE(A1,MAX(INDEX((MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)<>" ")*ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),,))+1,LEN(A1),""),"")**

Comment: Dammit..... I knew they existed.... I go confused as I was searching for trimleft and trimright. You can also just nest them in the formula as well `LTRIM(RTRIM(range))`

Comment: My Excel is not recognizing LTRIM or RTRIM. The Excel I have is part of MS Office Pro Plus 2010.

Comment: After briefly skimming over https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx, I successfully added this function to my sheet. If, after a day or two, no one comes up with an answer that doesn't require vba, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I notice that simply saying TRIMLR = LTrim(RTrim(Target.Value)) in the VBA function also works for me.

Comment: Yep, well spotted @Matt.  I've updated the code to reflect that.  I'm sure there's a non VBA answer, but it's 17:30 on a Friday.  Might have a think about it over the weekend.

Comment: Pnuts is correct, the VBA `Trim` function performs just as the asker needs, as a matter of fact to trim all duplicated spaces in VBA the command to use is `Application.Trim(string)` or `WorksheetFunction.Trim(string)`. Just try this:   `Const kTest = "  Trim  this  now  "`   
`Debug.Print "[" & kTest & "]"`   
`Debug.Print "[" & Trim(kTest) & "]"`   
`Debug.Print "[" & Application.Trim(kTest) & "]"`   
`Debug.Print "[" & WorksheetFunction.Trim(kTest) & "]"`

Comment: Well I'll be.... you're right @pnuts.  Tried to down vote the answer, but can't on my own answer.  You'd best add it as an answer so it can become the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Found out the hard way only yesterday that Excel's TRIM eliminates consecutive spaces within the string. Out of sheer annoyance I came up with a way of implementing standard trim() using only worksheet functions (with some help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string) answer). It's not pretty though:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),A1),FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1),"@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1),""))))-FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),A1)+1)
```

(if your text happens to contain @, then use a different unusual character in the formula)

Explanation:

- `LEFT(TRIM(A1),1)` gives the first non-whitespace character, so `FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),A1)` gives the position of this in the original string
- as per the linked answer,  this would find the last \ in the string. `=FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))`

  Replace \ in the forumla with `RIGHT(TRIM(A1, 1))`, and you find the location of the last non-whitespace character in the original string, i.e.   `FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1),"@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1),""))))`
- now that we have the first and last non-whitespace positions, we can extract the trimmed string with `MID(A1, first, last-first+1)`

Comment: Wow, all this just to eliminate leading and trailing whitespace. What a pain! Well, thanks for the contribution.

Comment: Good formula.  Who would want to write it, but once written this was an easy drop-in solution.