# Microsoft Excel: How to extract "text with quotes "from quotation marks"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to extract text containing quotes from quotation marks. Example, TRADE HOUSE "LLC"MEXICAN APPLES" THROUGH TESCO. I need to have in an adjacent cell "LLC"MEXICAN APPLES".

I tried

```
=MID(A1, SEARCH("""",A1, SEARCH("""",A1)-SEARCH("""", A1))
```

It did not work. I cannot understand how to set the length of the text to be extracted. The length of the text varies.

Comment: Plese describe all the cases, the logic behind. What if you have abc"LLC""MEXICAN APPLES"xyz? Should it be "LLC""MEXICAN APPLES" or "LLC"MEXICAN APPLES"? What about abc"LLC"""MEXICAN APPLES"xyz?

Comment: It is a good question. I have a column with companies' names in every cell. And the names vary, they may be abc "llc"apple" xyz, may be abc "apple" xyz, may be abc "apple"; abc "llc""apple" xyz. The main idea is to extract text with all the quotes from outer quotation marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("""",A1),SEARCH("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""))))-LEN(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("""",A1)-1)))
```

You can change the character "^" to any other unusual character.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your string in cell **A1**

```
=MID(A1,FIND("""",A1),FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",""))))-FIND("""",A1))&""""
```

Mostly borrowed from here:
[Excel: last character/string match in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string)

This presumes that your strings don't have an @ symbol in them. If they do, use something different in the formula

Answer (score 1):

Find first quotes in cell B1:

```
=SEARCH(CHAR(34);A1)
```

Find next quotes in cell C1:

```
=SEARCH(CHAR(34);A1;B1+1)
```

Formula in cell D1:

```
=MID(A1;B1+1;C1-B1-1)
```