# How to split using the last backslash character as delimiter in excel 2013?

Tags: excel

We have a list with 1000's of values in a single column.The values will be in this format

```
W:\RT_QAQC\Received\20160411_GDM_QA\VD\RegRef\Afr\Geology\IAE_Geology_Africa_10M
W:\RT_QAQC\Received\20160411_GDM_QA\VD\GlobRef\Ind\GIS\SS_GIS_Ind
```

I would like to split it using the last backslash a delemiter. So the result will be

```
W:\RT_QAQC\Received\20160411_GDM_QA\VD\RegRef\Afr\Geology
W:\RT_QAQC\Received\20160411_GDM_QA\VD\GlobRef\Ind\GIS
```

And in the next column,

```
IAE_Geology_Africa_10M
SS_GIS_Ind
```

I've tried with this one

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

But it's only copying the characters after the last backslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))-1)
```

[image]

This uses a simple technique to determine the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string.

Another approach is to use [tigeravatar's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string)

Comment: I was just about to explore the MID approach.  Thought it would be cleaner

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Very clever! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source data is in column A and you do not have a header row and your data start in row 1.  In C1 use the formula you posted as it seems to do what you want for the second column.  It also makes our life easIer on how to deal with the first column.  In B1 place the following.

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(C1)-1)
```

Results

[image]

Comment: LEN(C1)+1. Thats the problem. the length of the characters are not unifrom

Comment: Change the +1 to a -1 and you are off to the races