# How to extract parsed data from once cell to another

Tags: excel, google-sheets, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, formulas

Given a spreadsheet cell containing a string that consists of a hyphenated series of character segments, I need to extract the last segment.

For example, consider column A containing data strings like `XX-XXX-X-XX-XX-G10`, where `X` denotes any character. What formula would I need to place in column B to get `G10` as a result?

```
            A                B
1   XX-XXX-X-XX-XX-G10      G10
```

I'm looking for a formula that could work in in Libre Office Calc, Open Office Calc, MS Excel, or Google Sheets.

Comment: Thanks @Mogsdad for edit and clarifying my question :)

Comment: Glad to - wow, 5 answers! (Of course, if you'd mentioned that the part you wanted was always 3 characters, it would have been much, much, much simpler!)

Comment: Yeah. I'm still learning SO ;) to be more precise in problem explanation. Many thanks again for help and time @Mogsdad (im worried to be downvoted ass hell! ;D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility in LO Calc is to use the general purpose regular expression macro shown here: https://superuser.com/a/1072196/541756.  Then the cell formula would be similar to JPV's answer:

```
=REFIND(A1,"([^-]+$)")
```

Comment: And how about that case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095773/how-to-extract-data-from-one-cell-to-another

Answer (score 2):

If you are using google sheets, regexextract would be possible too:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[^-]+$")
```

Comment: Most elegant solution - i'm really missing a regex-capable replace function in LO Calc!

Answer (score 2):

In LibreOffice Calc and OpenOffice Calc, you can use a regular expression to determine the position of the text after the last `-` character:

```
=SEARCH("-[:alnum:]+$";A1)
```

will return `15` if A1 contains `XX-XXX-X-XX-XX-G10`.

Now, you can use this value to get the text "behind" that position, using the RIGHT() function:

```
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-SEARCH("-[:alnum:]+$";A1))
```

Split up on multiple lines:

```vb
=RIGHT(                ' return text beginning from the right...
    A1;                ' of cell A1 ...
    LEN(A1)            ' start at lenght(A1) = 18
    -                  ' minus ...
    SEARCH(            ' position ...
        "-[:alnum:]+$" ' of last "-" ...
        ;A1            ' in cell A1 = 15 ==> last three characters
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want the characters that appear at the end of a string, to the right of the last instance of a hyphen character, `"-"`.

This formula, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18617720), works in Excel, *Calc & Google Sheets:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Explanation:

- `SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",new_string)` will find each hyphen (`"-"`) in the original string from cell `A1` and replace it with a `new_string`.
- `REPT(" ",LEN(A1))` is a string of repeated space characters (`" "`), the same length as the original string in cell `A1`.
- `TRIM(RIGHT(string,count))` will get the right-most `count` characters, and trim off leading and trailing spaces. Since the string was previously padded out by replacing hyphens with spaces, and `count` is the same `LEN(A1)` used for that padding, the last `count` characters consists of a bunch of spaces followed by whatever followed the last hyphen!

In Google Sheets, an alternative approach is to use the SPLIT function to break the value from column A into an array, then select the last element. (Excel-VBA has a `split()` function, so you could make this work in Excel by writing VBA code to provide it as a custom function.)

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"-"),0,COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,"-")))
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found simply solution:**

> =RIGHT(A1;3)

that gives me G10 as the result too! It works because COL A always have 3 chars at the end!

Comment: And how about that case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095773/how-to-extract-data-from-one-cell-to-another