# How to extract data from one cell to another

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

Given a spreadsheet cell containing a string that consists of a hyphenated series of character segments, I need to extract the fourth segment.

For example, consider column A containing data strings like XX-XXX-X-**G10**-XX-XXX, where X denotes any character. What formula would I need to place in column B to get G10 as a result?

```
            A                B
1   XX-XXX-X-G10-XX-XXX      G10
```

I'm looking for a formula that could work in in Libre Office Calc, Open Office Calc, MS Excel, or Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2):

It was very simple... **MID** was the right function:

> =MID(A1;10;3)

where:

- **A1** is my data
- **10** start from 10 character - in my case G
- **3** range of characters count from 10 (10, 11, 12)

Pros:

- simple

Cons:

- work only with constant strings

Comment: Use my formula if you want a variable-size string.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the following general-purpose macro (tested in LibreOffice):

```vb
Function SplitAndExtract(findIn As String, delims As String, _
                         Optional segment_param As Integer)
    ' findIn - string or cell to search in
    ' delims - the delimiters to split the string up by
    ' segment - which segment number to grab
    If IsMissing (segment_param) Then
        segment = 0
    Else
        segment = segment_param
    End If
    splits = Split(findIn, delims)
    If UBound(splits) < segment - 1 Then
        SplitAndExtract = "No result for that segment"
        MsgBox "No result for that segment"
         Exit Function
    Else
        SplitAndExtract = splits(segment)
    End If
End Function
```

Then set the cell formula to:

```
=SPLITANDEXTRACT(A1, "-", 3)
```

This is similar to my answer to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38085634/5100564.  Thanks to @Ralph for suggesting the `Split` method.

Comment: There is no mentioning of VBA. Instead the OP asked for a formula. With VBA it's easy and could actually be much shorter.

Comment: @Ralph -- did you see the other question that is linked?

Comment: Yes I did. So, you are a big fan of VBA. Great. Me too. Yet, the OP posted a new question without referencing this post. I guess there might be a reason to that. And indeed (as you can see in the post and his own answer) he was looking for a formula and not another VBA solution.