# Adding string after last '.' in cell in Excel

Tags: excel, split, concatenation

I have a list of emails (roughly 2000) in excel.  I need to add a string, "string" to the end of the domain, before the .com.

```
Before: email@yahoo.com
After: email@yahoo.**string**.com

Before: email@school.edu.com
After: email@school.edu.**string**.com
```

I tried to use concatenate but that doesnt seem correct...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If it *always* ends in `.com` and you want to insert some text, you can do this (assuming your original strings start in A1) in B1.  Let's say your custom string is stored in C1.

`=Left(A1,Len(A1)-4)&$C$1&".com"`

edit: if not always `.com`,  `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","." & $C$1 & ".",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))` (thanks @ScottCraner)

[image]

Comment: Just replace the `.` with `"." & $C$1 & "."` : `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","." & $C$1 & ".")`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Do you want to make that an answer? I was going to do more, but the OP just mentions `.com`. If not, I'll edit it in to my answer, but don't want to steal your mighty thunder!

Comment: Have at it, I do not have the time currently to post an answer.

Comment: You cant replace the dots because of the `email@school.edu.com` example. It would return `email@school.*string*.edu.*string*.com`

Comment: @Moacir Then it would be: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","." & $C$1 & ".",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))` and it will change the last only.

Answer (score 1):

Column A the origin email

Column B will be where you put the formula

Column C the string (Or if its the same string for all of them just replace C1 with it)

`=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1-4))&C1&RIGHT(A1,4)`

Remember this will only work if the last characters are always 4 (Like .com, .net and not .br, .au)

Answer (score 1):

Say we have text in **A1** with at least one period in the text and zero or more characters after the last period.  We [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string) that the position of the last period is given by:

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",CHAR(1),(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))))
```

So we put this in **B1** and in **C1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,B1-1) & "whatever" & MID(A1,B1,9999)
```

[image]

This approach does not depend on the length of the string following that last period.