# How can I extract the text after the last "\" in excel

Tags: excel

Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\8X4LL1D4\SkypeSetupFull[2].exe

Apps\2.0\AEGKT5T4.VH6\XNGEQD26.3YY\appl..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_7143a400115fde3f\ApplicationLauncher.exe

I need to extract the .exe file name from above list in excel. Does any formula can do it? Please help.

Comment: [You might want to have a look at this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18617720/2648024)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

or

```
=MID(A1,FIND("=",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","=",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))+1,256)
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]