# Extract the value after the last occurrence of space in Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data like this:

- lm-sample prod
- lm sample prod
- lm-exit nonprod-shared
- lm- value dev

I want to extract just the last value after the first space from right.  So in this example:

- prod
- prod
- nonprod-shared
- dev

I tried:

```
Env = 
Var FirstSpace = FIND(" ", 'AWS Reservations'[Account])
Return RIGHT('AWS Reservations'[Account],FirstSpace - 1)
```

But that is giving me odd results.  Would appreciate some help on solving this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were passing the start character index rather than desired character count to the `RIGHT()` function.

> Right(Text, NumberOfCharacters)

Try this:

```
Env = 
Var FirstSpace = FIND(" ", 'AWS Reservations'[Account])
Return RIGHT('AWS Reservations'[Account], LEN('AWS Reservations'[Account]) - FirstSpace)
```

Answer (score 12):

The lack of options for `FIND` or `SEARCH` to search from the end of the string makes this quite tricky.

You can use:

```
Env = TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE('AWS Reservations'[Account], " ", REPT(" ", LEN('AWS Reservations'[Account]))), LEN('AWS Reservations'[Account])))
```

Or break it down for better understanding:

```
Env = 
VAR string_length = LEN('AWS Reservations'[Account])
RETURN
TRIM(
    RIGHT(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            'AWS Reservations'[Account],
            " ",
            REPT(" ", string_length)
        ),
        string_length
    )
)
```

Take `lm-sample prod` as an example.

First, we use `REPT(" ", string_length)` to create a string of

```
"              "
```

which has the same length as the value `lm-sample prod`.

Then, we substitute all the occurrences of " " with this extra long

```
"              "
```

and the string will become

```
lm-sample              prod
```

After that, we'll be comfortable getting the substring of `string_length` from the right, i.e.

```
"          prod"
```

Finally, we trim the result to get what we want, `prod`.

Results:

[image: results]

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18617720/2684954)

Comment: Wasn't sure how to give two answers credit.  This one and the one below are both good options.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe `FIND(" ", 'AWS Reservations'[Account])` gives you the first occurrence of space, not last, so the other answer is actually wrong. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYYry.png

Answer (score 0):

A minor clarification that might help others: if you're searching for the last instance of a string part separated by *other* than space, say period (.), e.g. to get "third" from "first.second.third" you'd need to substitute period for space in the *first* " ", but keep the *second* " ", as that's the "extra long" string, TRIM'ed out ...