# Extracting Specifc text string sections between two characters in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a sheet of text strings like the example:

```
06767996*Seg 010 Bligh St*Ernest Phillips Ave*Cooma*Adams Avenue Cooma*0.08
```

Where I want to extract the text between the last and second last astrix using excel formula. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you always have the same number of asterisks in each string or will it vary? Also, have you considered using text to columns with `*` as a delimiter?

Comment: Use [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) - That'll do exactly what you need, and more

Comment: If you need to do this in excel you will need to use a combination of `Mid`, `Find`, and [this (yikes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function NextToLast(sin As String) As String
    arr = Split(sin, "*")
    NextToLast = arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**