# How do I delete the last line of a multi-line cell

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with roughly 4000 rows of multi-line cells and I need to delete last line of each cell.

All cells are formatted like this - also last line of each cell begins with the same word (CODE:) but the length can vary:

```
this is the first line
this is the second line
this is the third line
CODE: 123456789
```

To:

```
this is the first line
this is the second line
this is the third line
```

I've also tried replacing line breaks with the "|" symbol and using a formula that deletes everything after the last "|" but had no success and pretty much every formula I've found returns an error in Excel.

```
this is the first line|this is the second line|this is the third line|CODE:123456789
```

To:

```
this is the first line|this is the second line|this is the third line
```

Multi-line or with symbol doesn't matter - either way works for me.

Comment: What is a multi-line cell? A merged cell?

Comment: A cell that contains line breaks (alt+enter), my bad.

Comment: Marked as duplicate, use the code in the link to find the position of the last "|" then use mid to select everything up to that character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: last character/string match in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string)

Comment: what version of Excel?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a formula or VBA solution or either?

Comment: Excel 2013, I tried the formula JeffUK linked and it also returns an error. Looking for ANY solution, formula or VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your text is in A1, try:

```
=LEFT(A1;FIND("CODE: ";A1)-1)
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** If you do `-2` instead of `-1`, you will get rid of the last line break too (actually the image is with `-2` instead of `-1`)

Comment: Very effective :)

Answer (score 3):

To enter this in a new cell:

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")))),LEN(A1),"")
```

The formula replaces the last `lf` character with a rarely used character `CHAR(1)` and then replaces everything from that character to the end with a null string.

Be sure to enable `wrap text` on the new cell.

[image]

If you want to replace it in the same cell, you will need VBA