# Delete everything in a string before the first period in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following text

```
Stack.over.flow 
sweet.stand.pro.flow
stop.fly.keep.flow
tank.staff.snack.flow 
stop.flow.over.flow
```

I want a Formula in excel giving the following output:

```
Stack.over.flow -------> over.flow
sweet.stand.pro.flow --> pro.flow
stop.fly.keep.flow ----> keep.flow 
tank.staff.snack.flow -> snack.flow
stop.flow.over.flow ---> over.flow
```

How can I achieve that please?

Comment: Does this help? https://trumpexcel.com/find-characters-last-position/  The only difference is that they are trying to find the last slash instead of the last dot.

Comment: And this may help as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks a lot, this formula find and delete last position of a forward slash and extract all the text to the right of it. What I want is the to skip the last dot or slash or whatever and jump to the next one and delete everything to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this which finds the second to last `.` and then returns all the string after that:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","{{{",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))-1))+1,LEN(A1)),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott .. Exactly what I Need .. That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

B1

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",66),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",))-1),66))
```

B1  Array formula

```
=VLOOKUP(".*.*",RIGHT(A1,ROW($1:$23)+{1,0}),2,)
```

Answer (score 0):

another alternative solution using FILTERXML (not available for non-Windows computers):
`=TEXTJOIN(".",0,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-1]"),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"))`