# Excel-Extracting Value Between Two Characters that Repeat Twice

Tags: excel

I have a column with entries that follow a similar format as the example below:
ABC - Adam Smith (T) (ABCadasmi)
ABC - John Carter (V) (ABCjohcar)

I'm looking to extract the "ABCadasmi" and "ABCjohcar" strings from these entries. Is there an Excel formula that can do this?

Comment: Probably. It should be easy enough to get formulas to extract the strings you are looking for. Will all your data be exactly like the single example you give?

Comment: Some entries are missing the first (T) or (V) values.

Comment: Have you tried `Find`, looking for `ABC` with a `start_num` of (say) `4`?

Comment: Or just look for strings longer than 1 character between `(` and `)` and grab it

Comment: Try this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string. Or if you don't need to repeat this often, just use Text-To-Columns first and split on delimiter, then enter the '(' as the delimiter.