# Searching comma-separated numbers within a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with many comma-separated numbers, e.g.:

```
   100633,101

    123,12

   100633,1000
```

How do I search whether a particular cell contains the number `100633`?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617175/excel-check-if-a-cell-contains-a-substring

Comment: @VDohnal: That's also what I thought at first, but a simple string search won't always work: it will erroneously return `TRUE` for e.g. `1,2,3,999100633999`. Gotta look at the entire comma-separated value.

Comment: Are there always only two numbers? Or is it sometimes a longer list? Is `100633` always first in the list, when it does occur?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett You are right but I cannot believe that such a simple task cannot be accomplished without using VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to @Jean-François Corbett correct remark and based on the following answer

[Check whether a cell contains a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617175/check-whether-a-cell-contains-a-substring)

here is a formula that searches the cell `A1` for the text `100633` considering only comma separated values

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",100633,",","&A1&","))
```

It handles correctly text like `1,2,3,999100633999`

You can also use `FIND` instead of `SEARCH` function. `FIND` is case sensitive. With `SEARCH` you can use wildcard characters.

Comment: Doesn't this answer only work if "100633" is NOT FIRST in the comma-delimited list? IE, the search is for a number that STARTS WITH and ends with a comma. If it's the first number in the list, it won't start with a comma, and so will not be found?

Comment: @TomAuger No, since it searches within `","&A1&","` and not within just A1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first target cell is in A1, returns TRUE or FALSE:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(100633,A1))
```

Custom values to return if true or false:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(100633,A1)),'yes','no)
```

Comment: False positive on e.g. `1,2,3,999100633999`.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(FIND("100633",E11)=1,"Number Exists","Not Exists")
```

The formula searches for the text and returns whether it is present in the cell or not

Updated:
Try Using the following excel formula:

`=MID(E18,FIND("100633",E18),6)`

Comment: False positive on e.g. `1,2,3,999100633999`.

Comment: I 've tried using the following formula:=MID(E18,FIND("100633",E18),6)
hope it works fine

Comment: Well, that formula also says the number `100633` exists in that example I just gave. But clearly it doesn't. `999100633999` and `100633` are two very different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

VBA solution:

```
Function CommaSeparatedListContains(ByVal csv As String, ByVal v As String, _
    Optional ByVal delimiter As String = ",") As Boolean

    Dim i As Long
    Dim splitCsv() As String
    splitCsv = Split(csv, delimiter)
    CommaSeparatedListContains = False
    For i = LBound(splitCsv) To UBound(splitCsv)
        If splitCsv(i) = v Then
            CommaSeparatedListContains = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
=CommaSeparatedListContains(A1,100633)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the following method...

```
    private boolean isNumberInvolved(String column, String number_to_check){
        String[] numberArray = column.split(",");
        for(int i=0; i<numberArray.length; i++){
            if(numberArray[i].equals(number_to_check))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone ..That time I needed the solution quickly so used a very raw method...Now ,I am applying these methods. There are many correct answers for this apart for the one I checked (as answer). Bt I am not able to select all. So selected the one whose formulae I am applying . Thanks a lot again.