# if statement see "Men's/Mens/Men" or "Women's/Womens/Women" returning "Male or Female"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a very basic question. thanks for helping.

if the cell contains "Men's/Mens/Men" or "Women's/Womens/Women" then returning "Male" or "Female"

why the following is not working? and i want to make sure it

```
=if(a1=(or("Men's/Mens/Men","Women's/Womens/Women"),"Male","Female")
```

for example:

```
Items                                                  Gender
O'Neill Women's Knot My Problem Tank Shirt             Female
O'Neill Womens Love VW Tank Shirt                      Female
O'Neill Women India Armor Tank Shirt                   Female
O'Neill Men's Knows All Tank Shirt                     Male
O'Neill Mens Jack O'Neill Hookipa Short-Sleeve Shirt   Male
O'Neill Men Welder Long-Sleeve Shirt                   Male
```

i know i can use two conditional statements to make this work, but is there a way to use just one if and use some other functions? say OR?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using "or" wrong.

If there are only 2 possible answers (male and female):

```
=if(or(a1="Men's";a1="Mens";a1="Men");"Male";"Female")
```

Other than that, I'd use nested Ifs

Comment: Plus one but might be worth pointing out that the comma is used instead of the semicolon in some locales; including that of the OP.

Comment: Not working for me
`O'Neill Men's Knows All Tank Shirt,Female`
`O'Neill Mens Jack O'Neill Hookipa Short-Sleeve Shirt,Female`
`O'Neill Men Welder Long-Sleeve Shirt,Female`

Comment: Is your gender stored in column A? Did you drag down the formula? (so that it's A2 for second row, A3 for third and so on)

Comment: Are there any spaces in gender cells? I also presume that Item name (O'Neill) is stored in different column, right?

Comment: If you are only going to check for one gender (assuming the other on default) and you have to do it with some form of wildcard search wouldn't it be better to search for *Women* instead of *Men* ?

Answer (score 0):

Answered a number of times, i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617175/check-whether-a-cell-contains-a-substring)

In your case this should do the work:

`=IF(SEARCH(a1="Men"),"Male","Female")`